# jquery ajax call - every other attempt fails with xhr.status = 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

Here is my code:

```
  $('#select').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'custom-ajax/' + $(this).val(),
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response) {
        $('#container').html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
      }   
    }); 
  });
```

The first "change" of my select returns "undefined (undefined)" in the console, second change works as expected ($('#container').html(response);). third change returns undefined, fourth change returns as expected, etc.

In every case, the full URL to the ajax callback is being hit -- if I copy and paste that URL into a new browser window, I can hit refresh 100 times and every single time it loads successfully so I don't believe it has anything to do with the page not responding. It's worth mentioning that when the error callback runs it happens *immediately* after changing the dropdown -- I don't get the impression it's even attempting to call the provided URL.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not even calling the URL as you're suggesting, it suggests that the URL isn't valid.  Try seeing what this returns in a few test cases:

```
  $('#select').change(function() {
    var url = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'custom-ajax/' + $(this).val();
    alert(url);
    window.location = url;
  });
```

Comment: Great debugging idea! I inserted that code and every select change is forwarding me to the new URL properly. 

I should point out that the console also shows the full url that it attempted to hit when it returns "undefined" -- in which case I can copy-and-paste that URL and it loads fine.

Comment: Ok, can you provide the HTML and an example url path, i.e. whatever `Drupal.settings.basePath` returns so I can test it?

Comment: The HTML that is returned (1 example of many...):

<h2>VimNET Explorer</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum delor sit amet...</p>

Comment: No I mean the markup on the page.  The `#select` and `#container` for example.

Comment: `<select id="select">
  <option selected="selected" value="">- Choose a Category -</option>
  <option value="vimnet">VimNET Explorer</option>
  <option value="plc">PLC</option>
</select>

<div class="clear-block"></div>

<div id="container"></div>`

Comment: I assume that Javascript is inside a `$(document).ready()` block? Just checking.

Comment: Can you provide the backend script?  Based on the info you've given me, I don't think the JQuery is the problem.

Comment: Actually it's probably not that... Can you do a jsfiddle with all the html? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `$output = '';
$term_data_name = filter_xss(arg(1));
$result = db_query("SELECT ... WHERE term_data.name = '%s'", $term_data_name);
while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
      $node = node_load($row['nid']);
      $output .= '
      <div>
        <h2><a href="/node/' . $node->nid . '">' . $node->title . '</a></h2>
        ' . $node->content['body']['#value'] . '
      </div>';
}
print $output;
exit();`

Comment: Of course the "SELECT ... " is not the full SQL query, but I didn't want to include all of that in the comment.

Comment: Well, I'm getting "Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." -- it can't perform the request across domains.

Comment: Try removing `dataType: 'html'`

Comment: Otherwise, just try updating your JQuery to 1.5